# Chrome download location in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, download

I am using Chrome browser on Ubuntu. I downloaded a file from mega nz site and am not able to find it. Where can can find it?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome keeps a summary of the files it has downloaded at the bottom left of the screen. You can go to the button file you downloaded, click the up arrow and select "Show in Folder".

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on chrome to show all the downloads. Click on the **Show in folder** link located below the filename to navigate to the file location.